# Asymptotic behavior of Sturm-Liouville eigenvalues

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

I have two questions.

Consider the operator $Av = -v'' + a(x)v$ on $I = (0, L)$, with zero Dirichlet condition and $a \in C([0, L])$.

> 1. Let $(\lambda_n)$ denote the sequence of eigenvalues of $A$. Do we have that$$\left|\lambda_n - {{\pi^2 n^2}\over{L^2}}\right| \le \|a\|_{L^\infty(0, L)} \text{ for all }n?$$**Thoughts.** We probably want to use the Courant-Fischer min-max principle somehow?

Consider the general Sturm-Liouville operator$$Bu = -(pu')' + qu \text{ on }(0, L)$$ with zero Dirichlet condition. Assume that $p \in C^2([0, L])$, $p \ge \alpha > 0$ on $(0, L)$, and $q \in C([0, L])$.

> 2. Do the eigenvalues $(\mu_n)$ of the operator $B$ satisfy$$\left|\mu_n - {{\pi^2n^2}\over{L^2}}\right|\le C?$$

Comment: Yes, this is an immediate consequence of the min-max principle.

Comment: Or of the Sturm comparison theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the *first* question is **Yes**. It is a particular case of the inequality
$$\lambda_n(B)+\lambda_{\min}(C)\le\lambda_n(B+C)\le\lambda_n(B)+\lambda_{\max}(C)$$
for self-adjoint operators, which follows from Courant-Fisher formula. Here the Hilbert space is $L^2(0,1)$ and 
$$B=-D_x^2,\quad C=a,\qquad A=B+C.$$
We have $\lambda_n(B)=\frac{p^2n^2}{L^2}$ and
$$\lambda_{\min}(C)=\min_xa(x),\qquad\lambda_{\max}(C)=\max_xa(x).$$

The answer to the *second* question is **No**. Just take $q\equiv0$ and $p\ne1$ a positive constant. Then 
$$\lambda_n=p\frac{\pi^2n^2}{L^2}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can be found on Wikipedia :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_ordinary_differential_equations

In particular, you will see that after a change of variables the general case gets reduced to the first one (on a different interval).