# Eigenvalues of the operator $A = -v'' + B(x) v$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

How can I prove that for the eigenvalues of the operator $$A := -v'' + B(x) v$$ on $(0,L)$ with zero Dirichlet boundary condition it holds that
$$
\left| \lambda_n - \frac{\pi^2n^2}{L^2}\right| \le ||B||_{L^\infty(0,L)}
$$
using the Courant-Fischer min-max principle?

Also, is it true that the corresponding eigenfunction form a hortonormal basis of $L^2$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asymptotic behavior of Sturm-Liouville eigenvalues](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232064/asymptotic-behavior-of-sturm-liouville-eigenvalues)

Comment: @mcd Thanks! This helps a lot, but it does not explain the key point: how do you prove $$\lambda_n(B)+\lambda_{\min}(C)\le\lambda_n(B+C)\le\lambda_n(B)+\lambda_{\max}(C) \ ?$$

Comment: @mcd Also, is it true that the corresponding eigenfunction form a basis of $L^2$?